# Present simple and present perfect tense

Tags: grammar

> My friend and I fell out last week because she thinks I'm in love with
> her boyfriend.

Can I use has thought instead of thinks in this situation?

Comment: [At the time] she thought I _was_ in love with him. It depends whether the (ex)friend still thinks so!

Comment: Maybe you *could*, but can you explain a reason why you want to?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to say:

> My friend and I had a falling out last week because she thinks I'm in love with her boyfriend

or

> My friend and I had a falling out last week because she thought that I was in love with her boyfriend

It depends as @Kate Bunting said, whether your friend still thinks you are in love with her boyfriend or not. I would say my first example would make the most sense, because since the event was so recent it is logical that your friend would still think you are in love with her boyfriend.